# Как прижать блок к низу страницы

Tags: html, css, flexbox

У меня есть контейнер с тремя блоками. 2 блока должны быть в центре контейнера, а третий снизу. Как сделать это используя флексы?

```css
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.first {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    /* другие стили */
}

.second {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    /* другие стили */
}

.third {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <p>first</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>second</p>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <p>third</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как прижать блок с классом `third` к низу страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то, возможно, вам стоит задать padding-top: 33%. Тем самым блоки начнут появляться начиная с 1/3 контейнера, что визуально создаст необходимый вам эффект.

Еще одним вариантов может быть создание дополнительного контейнера, который будет находиться перед .first

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в свой CSS вот это:

```
.container div:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
```